# How to connect points to draw a line segment and also make a parallel line w.r.t. line segment?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I want to draw a line segment passing through all the end points of my graph (the maximum value of a curve) which is plotted from a csv file. For this line segment I also need to draw a line parallel to this line segments by taking one point(known) as reference on the curve.

```
z,  x,  y
-40,0,0
-40,0.658,26.443
-40,1.316,47.128
-40,1.974,62.084
-40,2.632,73.336
-40,3.29,81.785
-40,3.948,87.501
-40,4.606,90.795
-40,5.264,92.491
-40,5.922,93.231
-40,6.58,93.41 - maximum value i.e end point of the curve
23,0,0
23,0.889,22.616
23,1.778,36.552
23,2.667,45.238
23,3.556,50.666
23,4.445,53.856
23,5.334,55.673
23,6.223,56.672
23,7.112,57.203
23,8.001,57.443
23,8.89,57.51- maximum value i.e end point of the curve
40,0,0
40,0.937,19.191
40,1.874,30.893
40,2.811,38.58
40,3.748,43.547
40,4.685,46.518
40,5.622,48.238
40,6.559,49.193
40,7.496,49.694
40,8.433,49.935
40,9.37,50.02- maximum value i.e end point of the curve
```

Above is the CSV file which I need to plot and the end points are mentioined. I need to connect all the end points with a line [as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZDSX.jpg) by using Pandas function and I tried the below code for doing this. The parallel line for instance take a single point on any curve w.r.t. this point the line to be drawn and should be parallel to the first line.

```
import csv
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

x=[]   # Initializing empty lists to store the 3 columns in csv
y=[]
z=[]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : []})

def readCSV(e):
        global df
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False)   #Reading CSV file using pandas
        read = csv.reader(df, delimiter = ",")
        fig = plt.figure()
        data_list = []
        ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
        df.set_index('x', inplace=True)  #Setting index
        df.groupby('z')['y'].plot(legend=True,ax=ax)   #grouping and plotting
        for line in ax.lines:
            xdata = line.get_xdata()
            ydata = line.get_ydata()
            s = line.append([6.58,8.89,9.37])
            r = line.append([93.41,57.51,50.02])
        ax.plot(s,r)
        ax.set_ylabel('y')
        ax.set_xlabel('x')
        ax.grid(True)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: To start you off - you can get the last coordinates of each line you have plotted. `for line in ax.lines:`, `line.get_xdata()`. Repeat for y data and append the last value of these into new lists. Plotting this will give you the straight line connecting the end of your existing lines

Comment: Can you please check the edited program. Is it correct way?

Answer (score 1):

To plot a line connecting the end points of your graph, one way would be to get the last set of coordinates for each line. This can be done using [`get_xdata()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_xdata) and [`get_ydata()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_ydata). This returns all the values, but we only want the *last* value. This can be done using the slice notation `[-1]`:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
print (my_list[-1])
# 5
```

So your code would become something like:

```
s = []
r = []

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", error_bad_lines=False)   #Reading CSV file using pandas

fig = plt.figure()
data_list = []
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
df.set_index('x', inplace=True)  #Setting index
df.groupby('z')['y'].plot(legend=True,ax=ax)   #grouping and plotting

for line in ax.lines:
    s.append(line.get_xdata()[-1])
    r.append(line.get_ydata()[-1])

ax.plot(s, r, color="black", linestyle=":")
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Great! this is what I am trying to do and for this line if I want to make a parallel line at a distance of say '(m,n)' ; which would be best method will it be offset of first line or by finding the distance between two lines and plotting at that particular coordinates

Comment: @Santo If it solved your problem you might consider accepting it.  [As described in here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)